# Wordpress Related Plugin - Adding an image

Tags: plugins, php

I'm using the Wordpress related plugin which is great but I would like to display the feature picture of the page.

It mentions on http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/related/installation/ about using a custom code.

Below is what I have so fave but I'm looking to add the feature image thumbnail to the related post.

```
<?php
    $rel = $related->show(get_the_ID(), true);
    foreach ($rel as $r) :
        echo '<li><a href=' . get_permalink($r->ID). '>' . $r->post_title . '</a>' . '</li>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have worked it out and have the following code:

```
<?php $rel = $related->show(get_the_ID(), true);
foreach ($rel as $r) :
echo '<a href='.get_permalink($r->ID).'>'.get_the_post_thumbnail($r->ID, array(50,50)).'<div class=page-related-title>'.$r->post_title.'</div>'.'</a>'.'<br />';
endforeach;
 ?>
```